# Pyobdc ModuleNotFound error for script despite all suggestions to resolve issue

Tags: python

I have a python script I created to get data from Github and import it into a Sqlite database, which works well. I now want to modify the script to import the data into a SQL Server Express database that is local on my machine and using Windows Authentication for the username/password. Here is the relevant script:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
import pyobdc

conn = sa.create_engine('mssql+pyobdc://@localhost\\SQLEXPRESS/COVID19?trusted_connection=yes&driver=ODBC+Driver+13+for+SQL+Server')
cur = conn.cursor()
```

When I run this, I get the following message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "COVIDtoDB.py", line 4, in
>   
>       import pyobdc ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyobdc'

I've done much searching on the Internet and have tried many different things to resolve this, including:

- updating Python to 3.8.2
- verifying only one version of Python is installed
- adding Python location to PATH variable
- verifying that pyodbc is installed in the same location as Python
- verifying that pyodbc is the latest version

I thought perhaps it was due to how I constructed my connection string. I would appreciate it if someone would review it to see if it's correct.

If the connection string is correct, any other thoughts on what I should try to fix this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct name of the module is `pyodbc`, not `pyobdc` as in your code.

Comment: Good god, talk about dyslexia setting in! Thank you for catching that. I'll make the change and see if it helps. This is why I needed someone to look at my script! :)

Comment: That fixed that issue. I have others, but I'll try to resolve them before posting them here. Thanks again for the catch!